# Pass Values Between Two Forms

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Is there any way to pass values between two forms. Let's say, I have two html form.

At Form 1, there's one field called name and submit button.

At Form 2, there's two field called name and email and submit button.

What I want to get is, At form 1, when i fill Form 1 name field and click submit, it will carry me to form 2 and name values that I filled will be inserted at names field of Form 2.

Is that possible to do that ?

If that so, please leave idea or snippets for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the forms are in separated pages, you can populate values in form two using the $_POST arrays:

**page 1**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
name <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
email <input type="email" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

At **page2.php**, grab values comming from $_POST and populate the form with these values:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
?>
<form action="pageX.php" method="post">
name <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"/><br/>
email <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Obviously you'll need to **validate** $_POST data in page2.php, but that's another issue...

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I will try it out now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't validated the code, probably some checks missing,  but you can do all in one page with two functions, something like:

```
function renderForm1($name $error)
{
   <?PHP
   if ($error != '')
   {
      echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
   }
   ?>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
      name <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="getname"/>
  </form>
}

function renderForm2($name, $email, $error)
{
   <?PHP
   if ($error != '')
   {
      echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
   }
   ?>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
     name <input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
     email <input type="email" name="email" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
}

if (isset($_POST['getname']))
{
  if(empty($_POST['name'])
  {
    $error='bla bla';
    renderForm1($name $error)
  }
  else
  {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    renderForm2($name, $email, $error)
  }
}
elseif (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  do whathever with fomr2
}
else
{
  renderForm1($name $error);
}
```

Comment: ok, i'm new at stackoverflow, just answered a 2010 post! :) newbie!